# Bug report: incorrect alignment of questions with new activity in tag feeds

Tags: bug, user-interface

When viewing a tag's question feed and sorting by active (such as [[geometry]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry?tab=Active)), there is a misalignment bug that happens when the "x questions with new activity" box spawns.

The box is not left-aligned in the same manner as the other elements in the question feed: [image: 1 question with new activity box misaligned]

After clicking on this, the question boxes that are put on top of the feed are noticeably misaligned with those that were there before: [image: misaligned question boxes]

This does not occur with the global questions feed sorted by active.

Reproduction details: Windows 10, Chrome version 89.0.4389.82 (64-bit), screenshots produced within the last hour (this has been happening for multiple days, though).